# Does not render instagram, twitter and other embedded in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to show content from instagram, twitter and other libraries that allow embedding in sites. The problem that I have is that it only renders the embedded content the first time and then when I go back to the same content the embed is not rendered again. :(

This is an example of what happens to me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcv94j 
*(I add the library js in index.html)*

I am located in test-1 the embedded content renders and when I go to test-2 the embedded content does not render

What solution could be given to this problem...? :S

Is there any way to trigger the events of the javascript libraries again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are including Instagram's `embed.js` which searches for certain elements in the DOM and replaces them by `iframe` elements which embed the post.

The script offers a global variable called `instgrm` which allows access to

```
instgrm.Embeds.process()
```

which repeats that search.
You may call this each time your component has rendered.

I have forked your example and modified it accordingly, following two different approaches:

1. [Calling a service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqyk4k) from the components
2. [Using a directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esnthv) for elements with a `data-instgrm-permalink` attribute

Comment: I'm getting an error: "element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'"

Comment: i needed to use `(window as any)[className]` to get it working

Answer (score 3):

If you're loading content dynamically (AJAX, for example), these embed services usually have a JavaScript API method that you need to call after inserting the contents into the page in order to render the posts.

Instagram, for example, have the [window.instgrm.Embeds.process()](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/), Facebook have [FB.XFBML.parse();](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/).

You will find something similar for Twitter and other social media embeds.

Answer (score 1):

replace  `<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>`
with `<script async src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>`
and move this line of code to index.html head section